# Laravel 5 Forms - Multiple File Upload inside form

Tags: forms, validation, laravel-5

I am pretty new when it comes to Laravel and have stumbled across a problem with file uploads inside a form:

Basically I need to upload multiple files when the form is submitted - the initial file upload elements are added dynamically as needed using JQuery as follows:

```
// Add upload fields to appointment form

var upload_button   = $('.upload-appointment-file'); // Upload Button ID
var upload_wrapper  = $('.upload-file-holder'); // Field Wrapper

$(upload_button).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(upload_wrapper).append(
        '<div>' +
        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group-sm">' +
            '<input type="file" name="file_name[]">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group-sm">' +
            '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="additional_name[]" placeholder="Document Title">' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 form-group-sm">' +
                '<select name="priority[]" class="form-control">' +
                    '<option value="">File Priority...</option>' +
                    '<option value="1">Important: Signature and Date Required</option>' +
                '</select>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +

        '<div class="row">' +
            '<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-9">' +
                '<textarea name="upload_description[]" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Additional instructions for Agent in relation to this file"></textarea>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>' +

        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info remove_upload">Remove</button><hr>' +
        '</div>'
    );
});

$(upload_wrapper).on("click",".remove_upload", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').slideUp(function(){$(this).remove()});
});
```

There are other static elements in this form using blade template. When the form is submitted I use a request class to validate the input (class CreateAppointmentRequest extends Request {}) which holds the validation rules in the rules method.

When the validation fails it returns to the original form page - here, I need to reconstruct the file upload input and repopulate the fields with the original data via a @for loop and injecting {{ old('additional_name')[$i] }} etc into the newly created fields (identical to the JQuery created fields).

My problem is that I can obtain all the fields except the original file_name field from the return data. file_name returns an empty array.

When I successfully submit the form file_name is constructed as follows:

"file_name" => array:1 [

```
0 => UploadedFile {#27

  -test: false

  -originalName: "pluto_planet.jpeg"

  -mimeType: "image/jpeg"

  -size: 53963

  -error: 0

}
```

]

All I need to do is somehow get the file name back from the validation error and repopulate the form. I am not sure if I am going about this in the correct way.

Comment: When a form submission fails validation, you want to display the form again, this time with a list of the uploaded files? I've never seen a form that works like this, and I think there's a reason for that: when the user clicks submit after correcting the validation error, there will not be any file data attached because the user hasn't uploaded anything. Are you planning on saving the data from the first submission & matching it up with the second? That might be possible, but it's gonna be complicated.

Comment: Thanks - this was the answer I was hoping not to get but explains the flaw in my logic :) I expect I should handle the uploads possibly via ajax as the main form is being completed ie. in a separate modal. Thanks for your moment of clarity